# How to retrieve data between two dates in parse.com using php

Tags: php, database, date, parse-platform

I am using parse php sdk to handle data in my web page. . I want to retrieve all data between two dates. I use the following code.

```
        $fdate=$_POST['fdate'];
        $tdate=$_POST['tdate'];

        $fd=date('Y-m-d\T00:00:00.000\Z', strtotime($fdate));

        $td=date('Y-m-d\T23:59:59.000\Z', strtotime($tdate));

        echo "Bookings from :" .$fd. " To:  ".$td;
        $query = new ParseQuery("Bookings");
        $query->greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt",$fd);
        $query->lessThanOrEqualTo("createdAt",$td);
        $query->descending("createdAt");
        $results = $query->find();
```

But this code not retrieving any data. How do I solve this?